# differential equation order 2 solution-exercice

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let $R(t)$ an function on $t$ définied in $\mathbb{R}.$
if we have 
$2 R'(t)=r(t) R(t)$ and $\dfrac{R''}{R} = \dfrac{r^2}{4} + \dfrac{r'}{2}$
how we found  $R?$

Comment: What is $r$ in relation to $R$? If they aren't related, why do you say what $R$ is but not $r$?

Comment: Down voting on the account that you changed the question dramatically after an answer was given and because you didn't address my comment above.

Comment: sorry Git Gud, i take your comment on a count but i dont' have information of $r.$ The question is : found $R$ ($r \neq 0$)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{R''}{R}=\frac{R''}{R'}\frac{R'}{R}=(\ln \left(R'\right))'r/2\\ \Rightarrow (\ln (R'))'r/2=r/2+r'/2\\ \Rightarrow (\ln (R'))'=1+\frac{r'}{r}=1+(\ln(r))'\quad(\mbox{Assuming}\ r\ne 0)\\ \Rightarrow \ln R'=t+\ln r+A\Rightarrow R'/r=ae^t\\ \Rightarrow R/2=ae^t\Rightarrow R=2ae^t$$

**Edit:** The new equation, following the lines of the steps above, leads to the following $$\left(\ln \frac{R'}{r}\right)'=r/2\\ \Rightarrow \left(\ln\left(\frac{R}{2}\right)\right)'=r/2=(\ln R)'$$ which is true by itself and hence does not give any new information.

Comment: $2 R'(t)=r(t) R(t)$ and $\dfrac{R''}{R} = \dfrac{r^2}{4} + \dfrac{r'}{2}$
how we found  $R?$

Comment: @jijii I have given all the steps in my answer to get the solution. If you have doubt about any step, then point it out to me.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay The OP changed the question. In his comment above he's giving you the new problem.

Comment: Oh, I simply supposed it was the old problem, didn't notice :-)